# Catch the [nullreferenceexception] on null

Tags: discussion, status-declined, burninate-request

Since we close everything related to a `NullReferenceException` as a [canonical dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it), do we really want to have these tags?

In which cases would a `[*Exception]` tag make any sense?

Comment: I think [tag:NullReferenceException] is a handy tag to have.  Search -> close as dupe -> rinse and repeat ;)

Comment: That canonical dupe would only be used for C# questions.

Comment: @gunr2171 From the tag wiki: *The .NET exception that is thrown when there is an attempt to reference (or use) a null or uninitialized object.* This canonical dupe also have an VB Answer.

Comment: Speaking from the Java side of this tag ([tag:nullpointerexception]), there *are* times in which it isn't a duplicate of the venerable canonical dupe that we have.  I don't disagree that this is rare, but having a tag to help address NPEs isn't the worst thing; at best, it gives us a clear path to start dupe closin'.

Comment: @Makoto I have seen one or two legitimate C# null reference exception questions. They are definitely not the norm, usually have a significant research effort put into them before asking and the answer is often an odd edge case or compilation problem.

Comment: @Steve The fact that the vast majority merit closure doesn't mean that the tag shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Servy I'm not suggesting that, just pointing out to Makoto the similarities being the .Net tag and Java tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid family of tags - there are enough cases where user observes [NRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)<sup>*</sup>, performs investigation and still get the exception.

Additionally if original question tagged properly it speeds up closure significantly as such canonical answers are on top of "potential duplicates" list. I frequently add tag first and refresh the question to close as duplicate as it is faster that way.

---

<sup>*</sup>Same applies to NRE/NPE, argument-out-of-range and other exceptions that have canonical answers for common root causes,